# How to use SQL FOR JSON PATH - dot notation for Custom JSON output

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to output a SQL query results in a custom JSON format.
I've tried several dot notation formats (I believe necessary) to get the
desired format.

The table has test data like

```
    Status = 'Test Status'
    Type = 'Test Type'
    Code = 'Test Code'
```

What I've tried;

```
        SELECT 
         [Status]  AS [id:950 .VALUE] 
        ,[Type]    AS [id:951 .VALUE]
        ,[Code]    AS [id:952 .VALUE] 
      FROM MyTable
      FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('fieldval')
```

Which gets me close with this;

```
   {
    "fieldval": [
        {
            "id:950 ": {
                "VALUE": Test Status"
            },
            "id:951 ": {
                "VALUE": "Test Type"
            },
            "id:952 ": {
                "VALUE": "Test Code"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I need it in this format

```
{
"type": "CustomJSON",
"fieldval": [
    {
        "id": "950",
        "value": "Test Status",
        "fieldName": "Status"
    },
    {
        "id": "951",
        "value": "Test Type",
        "fieldName": "Type"
    },
    {
        "id": "952",
        "value": "Test Code",
        "fieldName": "Code"
    }
]
}
```

What do I need to add/change? Thanks

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JSON_QUERY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) to add arrays of data to the outer JSON, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Example (
  ExampleID nvarchar(3), --<<-- nvarchar since the required JSON has strings here, not numbers.
  ExampleValue nvarchar(11),
  ExampleFieldName nvarchar(6)
);

insert dbo.Example (ExampleID, ExampleValue, ExampleFieldName)
values
  (N'950', N'Test Status', N'Status'),
  (N'951', N'Test Type', N'Type'),
  (N'952', N'Test Code', N'Code');

select
  N'CustomJSON' as [type],
  json_query((
    select
      ExampleID as [id],
      ExampleValue as [value],
      ExampleFieldName as [fieldName]
    from dbo.Example
    for json path
  )) as [fieldval]
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```

Which yields the desired result:

```json
{
    "type": "CustomJSON",
    "fieldval": [
        {
            "id": "950",
            "value": "Test Status",
            "fieldName": "Status"
        },
        {
            "id": "951",
            "value": "Test Type",
            "fieldName": "Type"
        },
        {
            "id": "952",
            "value": "Test Code",
            "fieldName": "Code"
        }
    ]
}
```